# How to Add a conditional expression in Azure Dataflow Window Transformation

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do I add an iif conditional expression in a window function under window Columns. I want to do the following:

```
iif(ID>5,(lag(op_hours,0)+lag(op_hours,1)+lag(op_hours,2)+lag(op_hours,3)+lag(op_hours,4)+lag(op_hours,5))/6,toDouble(4455))
```

under WindowColumns. However, the expression builder is throwing an error: "Columns should be wrapped within aggregate/Window functions" at `ID>5`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh well, according to the following link from Microsoft, this should be coming out of the box, [further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview)

Answer (score 0):

> How to Add a conditional expression in Azure Dataflow Window Transformation

In windows transformation we cannot give column name as single entity We have to pass it with the **Aggregate function** or **Windows function**

I tried to reproduce your scenario and getting similar error:

[image]

**To work around that I performed below steps:**

First, I created column as `Net Sales`  and gave the Lag expression to the windows Transformation To get the exact value:

[image]

It gave the output with Lag expression to all the values for particular window.

[image]

After I created a derived column with the same name and passed the conditional statement as

```
iif(Id>5,{ Net sales },toDouble(4455))
```

It is updating the `Net Sales` column values which have Id greater than 5 to decimal of 4455.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Like I am adding a bound like 5 rows Offset behind with Current row,and under window settings avg(ophours) so that i can get the 6 rolling average of ophours.

Comment: It does the same work as above right ?? After the window ,if we add a derived column as you mention with an iif ,that gives me the desired output ???

Comment: And what if i want to add a conditional expression like  iif( ID>5 and Type=="Forecast" ,Avg(Ophours ) ,toDouble(4455) . So here during the rolling average ,its checking for the rows satisfying 2 conditions . If we use derived column that doesnot work . How to do this kind of thing .